# Insertar java.sql.Timestamp en MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, timestamp

Cuando intento insertar un objeto `Timestamp` de `Java` en una columna del tipo `Timestamp` en **MySQL** recibo el siguiente error:

> com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Incorrect datetime value: '' for column 'fechhour' at row 1

¿Por qué ocurre esto?. Dejo el código que estoy usando a continuación:

**Codigo de la base de datos:**

```
CREATE DATABASE  IF NOT EXISTS `prueba`;
USE `prueba`;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `moments`;

CREATE TABLE `moments` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `fechhour` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

**Codigo de la miniaplicacion de java** para hacer la prueba:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JSpinner;

public class principal extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    Connection conSet;

    public principal() {
        initComponents();

        try {
            DriverManager.registerDriver(new com.mysql.jdbc.Driver());
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(principal.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/prueba";
        try{
            String url1 = System.getProperty("JDBC_URL");
            if (url1 != null)
                url = url1;
        }catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println("Seguridad ignorada");
        }
        try {
            conSet = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "root", "12345678");
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(principal.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }



    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")

        private void initComponents() {una ventana y un boton}

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        Timestamp hoy=getNow();
        Object[][] values=new Object[1][2];
        values[0][0]="fechhour";
        values[0][1]=hoy;
        System.out.println("la variable hoy es de la clase... "+hoy.getClass());
        try {
            insert("moments", values);
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(principal.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }                                        

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(principal.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(principal.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(principal.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(principal.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new principal().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;

    public void insert(String tableName, Object values[][]) throws SQLException{
        String cadCampos="(";
        String cadValues="(";
        for(int i=0; i<values.length; i++){
            cadCampos+=values[i][0];
            cadValues+="?";
            if(i!=values.length-1){
                cadCampos+=", ";
                cadValues+=", ";
            }
        }
        cadCampos+=")";
        cadValues+=")";
        PreparedStatement pstmt = conSet.prepareStatement ("insert into "+tableName+cadCampos+" values "+cadValues);
        for(int i=0; i<values.length; i++){
            System.out.println(values[i][0]+": "+values[i][1]);
            pstmt.setObject(i+1, values[i][1]);
        }
        System.out.println("insert into "+tableName+cadCampos+" values "+cadValues);
        pstmt.execute();
        pstmt = conSet.prepareStatement ("commit");
        pstmt.execute();
        pstmt.close();
    }

    public static java.sql.Timestamp getNow(){
        java.util.Calendar calendarHoy=Calendar.getInstance();
        java.util.Date hoy=calendarHoy.getTime();
        Timestamp hoySql=new Timestamp(hoy.getTime());
        System.out.println("Hoy es: "+hoySql);
        return hoySql;
    }

}
```

El código parece complejo porque esta copiado de lo que genera *NetBeans*, pero no es más que una ventana con un botón que al pulsarlo mete la fecha y hora actual en una base de datos con una sola tabla de 2 columnas: `id` y `moment`.

Por otro lado, la función `insert` esta creada para pasarle una tabla[x][2] con nombres de columnas y valores y el nombre de la tabla donde insertarlo. Quizás es una tontería porque habrá algo ya hecho para insertar objetos en MySQL, y como voy a realizar esa acción en muchas tablas diferentes dentro de mi proyecto he pensado hacerlo así.

Comment: Bienvenido a SOe. Como bien comentas, el código es complicado y aunque se ve la idea, no está claro el resultado. ¿Es un valor de SQL, o hay un fallo de lógica y estás intentando asignar la variable que no es al campo incorrecto? En general, se pide que aportes un [mcve]; en este caso, como muy mínimo, deberías indicar cuál es la sentencia SQL (que muestra en un `println`) y los valores para cada campo (que también imprimes)

Comment: Tanto el código de la base de datos como el de la miniaplicacion de java se pueden ejecutar y muestran el error. Lo único, es que al código de java le falta la parte del código generada por netbeans para dibujar la ventana y el botón. He probado a cambiar el objeto Timestamp por un String y la columna de Timestamp a varchar y funciona perfectamente, por lo que el problema no es una confusión de variable a un campo incorrecto.

Comment: Tú mismo, yo personalmente no voy a tomarme tanto trabajo para depurar el programa de un desconocido... Buena suerte.

Answer (score -1):

no sé si estoy mal, pero creo que en el MySQL los tipos de datos TIMESTAMP no se insertan, sino que se generan automáticamente al hacer una inserción, así que debes excluir la columna fechhour al llamar el insert en java

Comment: eso no es así, no existe una regla para eso, cualquier tipo de dato se inserta manual o por default eso lo decides tu como usuario

Comment: en todo caso en el código del OP el timestamp no se inserta manual por que con la condición `DEFAULT` estableció un valor por defecto para no tener que insertarlo, pero no por que esos valores no se puedan insertar manualmente en MySQL

Comment: tienes razón, viendo un poco no hay algo que impida eso, aunque en mi caso, siempre lo excluía de nombrar el campo, por eso lo sugerí como respuesta

Comment: es mejor responder aportando soluciones certeras y demostrables, por que esto parece mas una opinión que una respuesta

Comment: gracias por la aclaración, si mi respuesta o sugerencia no ayudó, entonces debo eliminarla ¿verdad?

Comment: no necesariamente @user116028 puedes editarla y mejorar tu aporte y de esa manera ayudar al OP y obtener puntos a favor